# Why can I access form's control inside setTimout but not outside?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm still new to Angular and I found very weird thing with form and setTimeout...
When I try to get TD's form control in setTimeout on OnInit it works but outside the setTimeout function it does not. The setTimeout's timeout is set to 0 miliseconds. Do you know what is causing this behavior? I don't want to wrap it in setTimeout function...

Template:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="text"
           name="email"
           id="email"
           [(ngModel)]="model.email"
           required
           email>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="subscription">Select subscription:</label>
    <select name="subscription"
            id="subscription"
            [(ngModel)]="model.subscription">
      <option value="basic">Basic</option>
      <option value="advanced">Advanced</option>
      <option value="pro">Pro</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="text"
           name="password"
           id="password"
           [(ngModel)]="model.password"
           required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('f') f: NgForm;

  model = {
    email: '',
    subscription: 'advanced',
    password: ''
  };

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.f.form.get('subscription')); // Works
    }, 0);
    console.log(this.f.form.get('subscription')); // Doesn't work
  }
}
```

Thank you for your answers + sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are unable to access the form outside of the `setTimeout` is when `ngOnInit` is called, the form has not yet been generated. The code running inside of `setTimeout` runs in a different tick and by that time, the form is created.

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit):

> ngOnInit is called right after the directive's data-bound properties have been checked for the first time, and before any of its children have been checked. It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

The form is not available until the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook is called. See [here for all the lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) and how to use them.

Comment: Same problem with the AfterViewInit hook.

Comment: Hmmmm...that's surprising. Can you try the `ngAfterContentInit` hook?

Comment: That doesn't work too. I even tried to create new Angular 5.2.0 project but didn't work either.